# Interpreting Wicket Debugbar output

Tags: java, wicket

I am investigating model detaching issues in Wicket 6.3.0 with help of Debugbar component http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/

However I have some difficulties interpreting the output. Is there documentation available that would explain what do the values mean (Inspector output/session size/page size)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspector links shows detailed information about some application settings, session and current page (whole component tree). Component tree-table shows their attributes and sizes.

Session link shows the page with the active sessions and their statistics.

The sizes are computed by default using serialization strategy. That means everything that can be, is serialized and size of the result output stream is measured. For Session it is the Wicket Session object. For Component it's the component tree with the current component as it's root.

Since Wicket 6.3.0 Component and IDetachable is detached before serialization, since Wicket 6.6.0 the detaching and serialization is performed on the cloned objects.

The size is (roughly) amount of bytes that will be written by the DefaultPageStore to IDataStore.